# How to git show a staged file?

Tags: git, git-stage, git-show

I can do `git show <some-commit>:path/to/some/file` but what do I replace `<some-commit>` to get the currently staged version of the file?

Context: I'm writing a pre-commit hook and I want to run a check on the staged files without resorting to stashing unstaged changes. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `git show :path/to/some/file`.

Files that are "staged" represent an index copy of the file that differs from some other copy, such as the current commit copy that you can access via `HEAD:path/to/some/file`.

Files that are stored in the index have a *stage number*, usually zero.  (Staging slots 1, 2, and 3 are used during conflicted merges.)

To refer to the copy of the file named *F* (in your case *F* = `path/to/some/file`), use the revision specifier `:number:F`.  In this case that's `:0:path/to/some/file`.  When the number is zero—which it usually is—you can omit one colon and the zero, leaving `:path/to/some/file`.

Note that when `git status` says nothing about that file, it's in the index, it's just that `:0:path/to/some/file` has the *same data* as `HEAD:path/to/some/file`.  If the file weren't in the index at all–in no staging slots—`git status` would tell you that the file is staged for deletion.

(Re the context: if you have space, I'd recommend doing a `git checkout-index` of *every* stage-zero-index-file into a temporary work area.  To easily test whether all index files are at stage zero, use `git write-tree`, which fails if any files are in staging slots other than zero.)

Comment: I knew it was something with the colon! Only that I remembered for the case when there is a conflict... not when there is no conflict. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it's that simple. Thank you!