# Reading a git staged file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

Is it possible for python to read a locally ***staged*** version of a file instead of the locally ***saved*** version of it?

For some context, I've got a pre-commit hook in my repo that calls a Python script to make sure some files include certain lines before staged changes can be committed. Currently I'm just using something like the following to read the files:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

// do something with the text
```

My problem is that the code checks the latest local save of each file as opposed to the staged copy of them. So you can run into a situation where the file is staged with mistakes, the mistakes are fixed and saved (but not committed), and then the pre-commit hook passes. Is there any way to access the staged version instead?

Comment: Related: [How can I get content of a file from git index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5032188/11082165)

Comment: You can access it with `git show :path` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60854287/636009)). I believe the way to do that in Python is `subprocess.check_output(['git', 'show', ':' + path])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read a staged file in a Git repository, you'll need to run `git show :<file>`; the `:` means "read from index". In your Python code, you could do something like:

```
text = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'show', f':{path}')
```

---

But this isn't strictly necessary; a better option may be to use the [`git checkout-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index) command to check out all files in the index to a temporary location and run your checks there.

E.g:

```
git checkout-index --prefix=$tmpdir -af
cd $tmpdir
...check things here...
```

If you're doing everything in Python, that might look like:

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix='precommit') as tmpdir:
    subprocess.check_call(['git', 'checkout-index', '--prefix', f'{tmpdir}/', '-af'])
    # check files here...
```

Comment: I appreciate the very in depth answer

Comment: For reference, would the user need to provide a value for tmpdir? This is meant to be automated such that it would look at the staged changes of the currently checked out branch.

Comment: Yes, the user would need to provide a value for `$tmpdir`. You can see this in the Python example; which uses `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` to create (and clean up) a temporary directory. In a shell script you could use `mktemp -d` to create the directory, and then arrange to clean it up afterwards using e.g. an `EXIT` trap.